# Ubuntu 14.04: PCI Compliance and openSSH

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox, ssh

I'm new to ubuntu and openssh.

Background:
I am currently on running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. There is oracle virtualbox installed as well. Virtual box run on Mandriva Drake.

I had to run a PCI compliance report and it said I failed. PCI website asked for more info on what kind of openSSH is running. Asked me to run

```
dpkg -l openssh
```

When I run

```
$dpkg -l openssh


dpkg-query: no packages found matching openssh
```

When I run ssh -V I get

`$ shh-V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`

Also, does it matter if the virtualbox openssh version is lower than the ubuntu 14.04 version? Most of my compliance problems have to do with openssh4.6 which only seems to be on the virtualbox.

When I run on virtual box konsole

```
ssh -V
```

I get

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
```

Does this mean I don't have openssh? How can I download it? Should I just upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to the latest version to pass the PCI? Is there a way to update the virtualbox openssh to something higher??

Comment: It's not called 'openssh'. Try looking for the `openssh-server` and `openssh-client` packages. I think it's understandable why PCI might have heartburn about an 11-year old version of SSH, but that seems like a Mandriva issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This actually helped me look further for the answer.